# Vue composition api - pass a variable to my component data() option?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

If I set a var in setup

```
 setup(props, context) {
    
        let name = "Tommy";
    }
```

Is it possible to set this so it can be used in the component?

```
data() {
    return {
      myName: name
    }
  },
```

I can access it in the template but not in any of the component methods. Even if I put it in the `onMounted` hook.

```
setup(props, context) {
  
    onMounted(() => {
    let name = "Tommy";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option api behaves differently than composition api, and exchanging properties/methods between the two api is a bad practice, in your case you could define a property in the setup hook and expose it to the template :

```
import {ref} from 'vue'

 setup(props, context) {
      const name = ref("Tommy");
      
  return{
    myName:name
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use it in the component, and even in the `data` option:

```js
data() {
    return {
      myname: this.name
    }
}
```

Though `myname` won't react to changes in `name`

Answer (score 1):

Also remember that, if you want to modify the value of your variable within the `setup` method, if the variable was initialized as a "ref", you have to explicitely access to the `.value` member

```
import {ref} from 'vue'

 setup(props, context) {
      const name = ref("Tommy");
      const fullName = name.value + " Hanks"
      
  return{
    myName:name,
    fullName
   }

}
```

In the template, you don't need to access to the value of the ref returned by the `setup` method. You just use the ref element, since `.value` is accessed implicitly in the template.